# Find who is the Super-User on a HDFS node

Tags: permissions, hdfs

[The HDFS's super-user is the user with the same identity as name node process itself.](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#The_Super-User)

HDFS node is started on CentOS.

How to find Linux user that started the HDFS node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All **`HDFS`** processes are started by the HDFS Superuser,

```
ps -ef | grep "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server" | grep -v "grep" | cut -d' ' -f1
```